# Slow population of data using GridView in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working in a web application in asp.net using c# and I want to display a large amount of rows from 10.000 - 1.000.000. The data bind fast, as I checked in step-by-step in debug mode, but when the page tries to display the GridView it takes forever. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is when clients (browsers) try do display a large amount of GUI. You should use `GridView` paging

Comment: Is your object filled before binding?  Usually updating takes the time.  Can you set the binding to null while updating and then rebind.

Comment: @jdweng It's empty and like I said in my question all the code runs fast, the display time is slow.

Comment: With those kind of numbers, abandon aspnet controls and write your own. Even if you would enable paging in a GridView, the entire dataset is still loaded every time. And I highly doubt a user will go through 100's of pages, so you might want to implement some filter.

Comment: @VDWWD you are right about the filters, but when you tell someone that you can populate data, then you can't tell them that can't see them all if he wants. What do you mean write my own? Like building an html table and display them in there?

Comment: There are many options. But you could also show no data untill a filter is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when clients (browsers) try do display (render) a large amount of GUI. Asking the client to render 10,000 - 1,000,000 rows can definitly take way too much time.

One solution to your problem is using paging using the `AllowPaging` with `PageSize` properties. This will limit the number of rows displayed in your `GridView` to what you set in the `PageSize` property.

**HTML**:

```
<asp:GridView   ID="gv" 
                runat="server" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging"
                OnPageIndexChanged="gv_PageIndexChanged"
                AllowPaging="true"
                PageSize="50">
        <Columns>
                ....
```

**Code behind**:

```
protected void gv_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // bind your data
    gv.DataBind();
}
protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewPageIndex == -1)
        gv.PageIndex = Int32.MaxValue;
    else
        gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

**Recommendation**: Using the above solution should solve the UI problem, but the huge amount data will **still be fetched**. I suggest paging both in the **SQL level** and in the **UI level**.

Comment: Keep in mind that all the rows are still loaded every time, even though only 50 are shown.

Comment: @VDWWD I know, but read the OP's question saying: *The data bind fast, as I checked in step-by-step in debug mode*

Comment: That is true, but loading one million rows to show only 50 seems such a waste.

Comment: @KobyDouek It worked! Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately, now when I change pages eventually I get System.OutOfMemoryException. :(
Additionally, I am not quite sure that I got your recommendation comment.
Thank you again tho!

Comment: @VDWWD Any better suggestion, because your argument seems really reasonable

Comment: For your exception, read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192408/SQL-Pager-Control-for-GridView-DataList-Repeater-D

Answer (score 0):

You should design a query for this problem, for example you want to display 10 records from 10,00000 record on each page in your gridview paging.

Pass three parameters ('@startRowIndex', '@startRowIndex', '@maximumRows') from your gridview in below select statement and use `ROW_NUMBER()` method (SQL Server 2005 above supports it) to get sequentially-increasing row number.

```
SELECT ...
FROM
(SELECT ... 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnName) as RowNum
FROM Employees e
) as DerivedTableName
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
```

**Link 1:** https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx